# How to reload a FutureBuilder in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, fetch, flutter-futurebuilder

I have a FutureBuilder here :

```
FutureBuilder<List<Task>>(
                          future:
                            getTasks(),
                          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Task>> snapshot){
                            if(snapshot.hasError){
                              return const Text('Erreur');
                            }
                            if(snapshot.hasData){
                              return ListView(
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                children: taskList.map((e) => TaskContainer(
                                  task: e
                                )).toList(),
                              );
                            }
                            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                          }
                        )
```

Which return a list of tasks as colored block container in a calendar as shown below :

[image]

The problem is whenever I navigate to another month in the calendar, the FutureBuilder is fetching the again fetching the data from the webservice, which duplicate the tasks every time I change months :

[image]

Here is the code of my functions to navigate between months :

```
    _toPreviousMonth(){
    setState(() {
      datess.clear();
      dayss.clear();
      startMonth = new DateTime(startMonth.year, startMonth.month - 1, 1);
    });
  }

  _toNextMonth(){
    setState(() {
      datess.clear();
      dayss.clear();
      startMonth = new DateTime(startMonth.year, startMonth.month + 1, 1);
    });
  }
```

Actually I don't mind the FutureBuilder fetching the data when I change month, because the final goal would be to display tasks from the selected day.

But what I would like is to have a way to suppress the containers build from the previous fetch as I navigate between months,

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: Could you show the code for `getTasks()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not showing how you are using snapshot in your `FututrBuilder`??

I suspect you are adding the tasks directly to a list everytime you re-build using `setState( )`.

**Solution:** reset your tasks `list` at the beginning of the `buid( )` method

```
@override Widget build(BuildContext context) {
yourTaskList = [] //if an array or adjust if other type
```